# Is it possible to automatically upload files when created to a web server?

Tags: java, webcam, filezilla

I am working on a project using a Raspberry Pi and a web cam to detect motion.

I have got it to a stage whereby it takes an image and saves it on my computer. What I am wondering is, is it possible to let FileZilla automatically upload the image to my webserver when a new image is taken? Or is there any other ways that I could achieve this?

Comment: I'm going to assume you're using some flavor of unix, in this case I would suggest using a cli ftp client or maybe rolling something of your own in java.

Comment: I will look into it thanks

Comment: you meant upload image file from your computer to server like dropbox?

Comment: If you want to save it to dropbox, use their REST API (https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/java). If you have an FTP server, use the FTP client API(http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html).

Comment: Oh my bad, didn't realize you're trying to go to dropbox. Have a look at their [java library](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the post is tagged `java`, I'm assuming that you're using a Java program already or have the basic knowledge to create a Java program.

On to the answer: yes, you basically have two options.
1. Upload from within the Java program. FTP is probably the easiest since most web servers will have an FTP server running. Here is a tutorial you can use: http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-file-upload-tutorial-and-example
2. Use another utility outside your Java program to upload the file to your webserver. `rsync` would be the tool of my choice (tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps)). When on a Linux machine (for example, the Pi) or a Mac, you can run a script that syncs the content of a local folder to a remote folder every x seconds:
`while true; do <rsync command hier> sleep 5s; done`
Note that that sleep period shouldn't be too short or you'll end up running multiple instances of rsync.
When on a Windows machine, you need to find another way to run a periodic process to trigger the rsync.

Comment: Ye worked perfect thanks very much @Bert Jan Schrijver